# MySQL Large Table Indexes - Recommended length of index

Tags: mysql, performance, index

I am working with a table that has a couple hundred million rows of data. It uses varchar(32) UUID's as it's keys both primary and foreign (there are two). I was wondering with this size of table, how much of each field do I need to index to keep good performance but not index every character of those three fields.

For example if I set an index length of 24 characters, will I see any noticeable difference in performance? I was hoping there might be some kind of algorithm out there that can be used to estimate performance based on length of field and length of index.

Currently the table is ~100GB in size, and the index is taking up over half of that space. I would like to recover some of that space, and reduce the growth rate of the table.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your question (how to cut index length), but an alternative to reach the same objective: use less space in your DB.

If you want to optimize storage you should *not* store UUIDs as `varchar(32)` (nor `character(32)`).

You can store them as `binary(16)` with no loss of information, and save (at least) 50% of space. A UUID contains 128 bits of information. If stored as a text representing the hexadecimal value, you use 4 bits of information out of every `character`, which employs 8 bits assuming the text is encoded as `ASCII` or `latin1`. So, you waste half your available bits. Storing the information in `binary` format, you waste none.

My response is heavily inspired in [Storing UUID Values in MySQL Tables](http://mysqlserverteam.com/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/), which I would recommend you read.

The following example shows you how to store the same UUID data in the two different formats:

```
 CREATE TABLE t
 (
      uuid_a character(32) PRIMARY KEY
     ,uuid_b binary(16) UNIQUE KEY
 ) ;
```

Both `uuid_a` and `uuid_b` will be used to store the same UUID, encoded in two different ways.

Assuming we have a table called `generator_64k` with 64k of data... we fill `t` with lots of `uuid()` using:

```
 -- We fill it with random data
 INSERT INTO 
     t 
 SELECT
      replace(u,'-','')             -- text version
     ,unhex(replace(u,'-',''))      -- binary version
 FROM
     (SELECT 
         uuid() AS u 
      FROM 
         generator_64k
     ) AS s0 ;
```

... and we add also a well known value:

```
 -- We fill it with one known piece of data
 INSERT INTO 
     t 
 SELECT
      replace(u,'-','')             -- text version
     ,unhex(replace(u,'-',''))      -- binary version
 FROM
     (SELECT
         'aab5d5fd-70c1-11e5-a4fb-b026b977eb28' AS u
     ) AS s0 ;
```

You can then query the table and look for the known value using either of the representations:

```
 -- Encoded as character(32)
 SELECT
     uuid_a, hex(uuid_b)
 FROM 
     t
 WHERE
     uuid_a = replace('aab5d5fd-70c1-11e5-a4fb-b026b977eb28', '-', '') ;

 -- Encoded as binary(16)
 SELECT
     uuid_a, hex(uuid_b)
 FROM 
     t
 WHERE
     uuid_b = unhex(replace('aab5d5fd-70c1-11e5-a4fb-b026b977eb28', '-', '')) ;
```

You get, in both cases, the same result:

```
 uuid_a                          | hex(uuid_b)                    
 :------------------------------- | :-------------------------------
 aab5d5fd70c111e5a4fbb026b977eb28 | AAB5D5FD70C111E5A4FBB026B977EB28
```

In practice, you would only use `uuid_b` in your table.

By doing this, you *halve* the amount of space used to store your UUIDs (both in table and indexes), without having to resort to using a substring in your index (which can affect your performance, and still not save that much).

*See all the code at dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=fba6a0f07b91e0a4db0d36947eec6ae7)*

Comment: This is really interesting, and looks like it could be quite useful for projects in the future, I am not sure how we could go about implementing something like this without a significant downtime, considering all the foreign keys in use that would need to be handled.

Comment: I am afraid you actually need some or a lot of downtime... You could, in principle, add a new column `new_uuid` of type `binary(16)` and let it be nullable. I am not sure about MySQL, but this shouldn't block the table, or at least not do it for too long. Do this for all UUIDs in use. Update this new column in batches. Finally, create indexes, change foreign keys. This bloats a lot the space used before you can start the shrinkage... by dropping the unneded columns (this takes a *long* time and *blocks* lots of things). I don't know the details of MySQL well enough to evaluate how much.

Comment: @joanolo - _Newer_ versions of MySQL _might_ be able to do as you described without significant downtime.  There are multiple `ALTER TABLE` actions (add, drop column and FK); it is not clear that each can be done without copying the table over, would would be terribly long.

Comment: I guess *drop columns* is the one that might block... but I actually don't know enough of the specifics of MySQL to be able to tell.

Answer (score 0):

You may be doomed.

- "Prefix indexes" (as in `INDEX(uuid(24)`) are not well optimized.  In some situations, the Optimizer ignores them and scans the table instead.  Not knowing all of your queries, I can't say.
- Moving to `BINARY(16)` is definitely an improvement in *space*.
- (Doomsday:)  As soon as the size of an index on a "uuid" exceeds what can be cached in RAM, performance goes down.  And it continues to go down as the table grows.  Shrinking the number of bytes in the index *delays* this fate, but does not *eliminate* it.  The reason is the randomness of UUIDs/GUIDs -- this effectively makes caching less and less useful.
- What generated the uuids?  Do you tend to touch "newer" rows?  There may be some hope, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid on a technique for packing Type 1 uuids to give you 'locality of reference'.

Since there is no generic solution for your question, please describe your application and provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  From those, we *may* be able to help with performance (and space) with some other technique.

Comment: Interesting to know about the prefix indexes not really helping due to how UUID's are formed. 

I think what we might end up having to do is drop at least one of the indexes (a foreign key we don't apparently use in any of our queries) and possibly remove the primary key indicator and it's index. It's a dead-end table, nothing will ever use it's primary-key as a foreign-key. 
I appreciate everyone's help and suggestions on this one. I think in the future I have convinced them to use Binary(16) instead of varchar(32) but we have to live with this system for the time being.